One specific span tag is empty with no attributes when using Selenium/SeleniumBase
I'm attempting to scrape data of baseball prospects on MLB.com with Python. When I open a browser manually and view the source HTML, I see the JSON data with everything I need in the single attribute data-init-state of a <span> tag. However, when I use Selenium or SeleniumBase, that <span> tag is completely empty with no attributes --> <span></span>  As a result, I can't access the data I need.
When I first started, I was using Selenium's find_element() and SeleniumBase's get_element() looking for the data-init-state attribute in the span element, but I kept getting errors that the element could not be found. Once I noticed the empty <span> tag in their HTML source, it was clear why it could not be found. I started looking for a cause and solution. So, for now, I'll just show how I'm getting the HTML source.
First I tried with regular Selenium webdriver:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from time import sleep

url = "https://www.mlb.com/prospects"

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless=new')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url)
sleep(10)

prospects_source_html = driver.page_source

with open('prospects_source_html.html', 'w') as file:
    file.write(prospects_source_html)


Thinking, perhaps, that the website detected the use of automation software and was restricting the data, I then tried with SeleniumBase:
from seleniumbase import SB

url = "https://www.mlb.com/prospects"

with SB(uc=True, test=True, incognito=True) as sb:
    sb.uc_open_with_reconnect(url, 8)
    sb.sleep(15)
    sb.save_page_source('prospects_source_html.html')


Thinking that maybe it was just taking extra time for that data to fill in on the site, I have tried extending sleep() to as long as 120 seconds. Unfortunately, same results.
I have tried running a headed version (removing the --headless=new option for Selenium, and using the headed=True argument for SeleniumBase), but that also did not make any difference with the empty <span> tag.
While testing with the headed version, I tried putting in an extra long sleep() time after the page loaded. Then, rather than sitting back and letting Selenium/SeleniumBase do it's thing, I manually right-clicked on the page, selected "View page source", and inspected the HTML right in the browser window. Interestingly, the data-init-state attribute and the JSON data were there in the <span> tag! Yet when I let the script continue and finish, the resulting saved HTML file still had the empty <span> tag.
I'm stumped... Is there maybe a script the site runs to populate that span after loading the page, but the site blocks running the script because it detects the presence of Selenium/SeleniumBase?
Does anyone know what's happening here? Is there any way to make this work?

Your code is not runnable due to syntax error(s). Please provide a Minimal Reproducible Example

Fixed. Not sure why the double-quotes around the url string weren't there, but they're there now. Thanks.

As I understand it, after the page is initialized, the <span data-init-state="..."></span> tag is displayed on the page and then cleared.
To retrieve data from the data-init-state attribute, you can send an HTTP request that fetches the full page code before the page is initialized, without using Selenium.
Here is a sample code:
import re
import html
import json
import requests

pattern = re.compile(r'state="([^"]+)', re.M)

url = "https://www.mlb.com/prospects"
response = requests.get(url)
html_content = response.content.decode()

if match := pattern.search(html_content):
    raw_data = html.unescape(match.group(1))
    data = json.loads(raw_data)

    with open("data.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(data, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)

The data from the attribute data-init-state is saved in a file named data.json.

Thank you! This works very well.... unless the site decides to hit you with Cloudflare's Turnstile "verify you are human" checkbox page. If I'm connected through a VPN, the Turnstile page almost always comes up first, so this method doesn't work in that case. I guess Seleniumbase would be necessary in that situation to get by Turnstile. Any idea how that could be accomplished?
